# Find matching elements in array using async/await and promise.all

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, protractor

filterdList.length value always equal total number of elements with below code. So this method always returning false. There is only one item in the table that is matching with given name.

```
async itemExists(name) : Promise<boolean>{
const itemList = await element.all(this.itemList)
const filterdList= await Promise.all(itemList.filter( async (item) =>{
  let text = await item.getText();
  if (text == name) {
    return true;
  }
}));

 return await filterdList.length == 1;
}
```

calling this method as below

```
console.log(await itemExists('unique item name'));
```

Comment: Where is `name` defined?

Comment: name is passed as a parameter to this method.

Comment: What is `itemList`? I don't think its `filter` method will take a promise-returning callback.

Comment: You definitely don't need to (and should not) `await` the boolean result of the `filterdList.length == 1` comparison.

Comment: Is `itemList` an array of `Promise` values or an array of `Promise`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` is only necessary once within `async` function

```
async function itemExists(name) {
  const itemList = await Promise.all(element.all(this.itemList)
                   .map(item => item.getText()));
  const filterdList = itemList.filter(item => text === name);
  return filterdList.length == 1;
}

itemsExists(name).then(bool => console.log(bool));
```

```js
async function itemExists(name) {
  const itemList = await Promise.all(['unique item name', 'not unique item name'].map(item => Promise.resolve(item)))
  const filterdList = itemList.filter(item => item == name);
  return filterdList.length === 1;
}

itemExists('unique item name').then(bool => console.log(bool));
```

Comment: I am getting following error while implementing this in type script. Any clue ? `[ts] Argument of type 'Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<{} | PromiseLike<{}>> | PromiseLike<Iterable<{} | PromiseLike<{}>>>'.`  @guest271314

Comment: sorted it out `const itemExists = async (elementAll: ElementArrayFinder, name: string) => {
    const fn = await elementAll.map((elm: ElementFinder) => { return elm.getText() });
    const itemList = await PromiseBB.all(fn);
    const filterdList = itemList.filter(item => item === name);
    return filterdList.length == 1;    
}`

Comment: "Await is only necessary once within async function"

That's the case here, but not in general. If you are awaiting another promise, you must await it.

Answer (score 2):

This line is all kinds of wrong: `return await filterdList.length == 1;`

First, it looks like you want to return a `Promise`, not a `boolean`. Don't use the await keyword in that statement if that's your goal. Secondly, you can't `await` a `boolean`. You can only use `await` on `Promise` instances. Instead, you can do something like `var list = await filterdList`, then you can check the length of `list` later.

I recommend rebuilding this method from scratch, and test with 
`console.log` statements along the way. It will give you a better understanding of what is going wrong, and where. Be especially careful about what you are passing to `Promise.all`. If it's not an array of Promises, then it's not going to behave correctly.

You should probably not filter the array until all of the Promises have resolved. You can get all of the names, then filter. The line below will output the resolved item names, which you can filter through.

```
var itemNames = await Promise.all(itemList.map(item => item.getName()))
itemNames.filter(...).length
```